# Let $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers, such that $a+b+c=1$. Then prove that $\frac{a-bc}{a+bc} +\frac {b-ca}{b+ca} +\frac {c-ab}{c+ab} \leq \frac32$

Tags: inequality, theorem-provers

Let $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers, such that $a+b+c=1$. Then prove that $\frac{a-bc}{a+bc} + \frac{b-ca}{b+ca} + \frac{c-ab}{c+ab} \leq \frac32$

Who can help me ? I dont know what inequality need use in this case ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my bad we need prove 

$\frac {a-bc}{a+bc} + \frac{b-ca}{b+ca} + \frac{c-ab}{c+ab} \leq \frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observations towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

- If we normalize the denominator, we get $ a(a+b+c) + bc  = a^2 + ab +ac + bc = (a+b)(a+c)$.

  - This allows us to easily combine denominators, so the simplification could be useful.
- If we normalize the numerator, then it's not as pretty. How can we get rid of the $-bc$?

  - We can get rid of it by adding 1 to the term.
  - WTS $\sum \frac{ 2a}{ (a+b)(a+c) } \leq \frac{ 9}{2}$
- Now let's make common denominator

  - WTS $\sum \frac{ 2a(b+c) } { (a+b)(a+c) } \leq \frac{ 9}{2} $.
- Now let's clear denominators and combine terms

  - WTS $8(ab+bc+ca) \leq 9 (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) $
- Now let's normalize the inequality

  - WTS $8(a+b+c) (ab+bc+ca) \leq 9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$.
- This is a well-known inequality.

  - Just expand and cancel terms, then apply AM-GM.
  - Hence equality holds iff $ a = b = c = \frac{1}{3}$ .

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{align}
LHS &=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a-bc}{a+bc}\\
&= \sum_{cyc}\frac{a-bc}{1-(b+c)+bc}\\
&= \sum_{cyc}\frac{a-bc}{(1-b)(1-c)}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{cyc}\left((a-bc)(1-a)\right)}{(1-b)(1-c)(1-c)}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{cyc}\left(a-a^2-bc+abc\right)}{(1-b)(1-c)(1-c)}\\
&= \frac{1-\sum_{cyc}a^2 -\sum_{cyc}ab+3abc}{1-\sum_{cyc}a +\sum_{cyc}ab-abc}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{cyc}ab+3abc}{\sum_{cyc}ab-abc}
\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
LHS \le \frac{3}{2}&\iff  2\left(\sum_{cyc}ab+3abc\right) \le 3\left(\sum_{cyc}ab-abc  \right)\\
&\iff \sum_{cyc}ab \ge 9abc\\
&\iff \sum_{cyc}a \cdot \sum_{cyc}ab \ge 9abc \\
&\iff \sum_{cyc}a^2b + \sum_{cyc}ab^2 + 3abc \ge 9abc \\
&\iff \sum_{cyc}a^2b + \sum_{cyc}ab^2 \ge 6abc \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Applying the AM-GM inequality, we can prove that $(1)$ holds true:
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b  \ge 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b\cdot b^2c\cdot c^2a} = 3abc $$
$$\sum_{cyc}ab^2  \ge 3\sqrt[3]{ab^2\cdot bc^2\cdot ca^2} = 3abc $$

The equality occurs if and only if $a=b=c= 1/3$.

Q.E.D

Comment: Any idea if there's a way that allows us to avoid expanding out the denominator and manipulating it (cross multiply and subtract the numerator)? $\quad$ BTW $\sum a \sum ab \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{abc} \times 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2} = 9 abc$.